# Email subject with special Charaters to send with perl

Tags: perl, sendmail, encode

I have to send emails with perl, here is the code:

```
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From => $tpl->{'from'},
    To => $tpl->{'to'},
    Subject => $subject_id_site . Encode::encode('MIME-Header',$subject_label). Encode::encode('MIME-Header', $tpl->{'subject'}),
    ReplyTo => $tpl->{'reply_to'},
    Encoding => 'quoted-printable',
    Type =>'text/html',
    Data => Encode::encode('utf8',$tpl->{'body'}),
);
```

If the subject contains Special Characters, for example: `[300584 / Yçàéè@test] subject`

Here is the email subject that I got sent by perl coding: `[300584 / YÃ§Ã Ã©Ã¨@test] subject`.

Actually I tried with `Encode::encode('UTF8',$subject_label)`, but it gets worse.

Comment: Do you have that data in your source code as a literal string or is `$subject_label` read from an external source?

Comment: @simbadque , yes the $subject_label reads from an external source

Comment: Please provide the output of `join "|", ( map { sprintf("%vX", $_) } $subject_id_site, $subject_label, $tpl->{'subject'} ), $subject_id_site . Encode::encode('MIME-Header',$subject_label). Encode::encode('MIME-Header', $tpl->{'subject'})`

Comment: @Subha_sri the `use utf8` is useless in this case, that's why I asked if the data is in the code directly. The `utf8` pragma tells Perl that the source code is in utf8. That's not the case here.

Comment: @ikegami i may have a syntax error  , u mean like this : `  Subject =>  join "|", ( map { sprintf("%vX", $_) } $subject_id_site, $subject_label, $tpl->{'subject'} ),$subject_id_site.Encode::encode('MIME-Header',$subject_label). Encode::encode('MIME-Header', $tpl->{'subject'})`

Comment: No, provide us with the string that results from that expression

Answer (score 0):

The email subject looks "twice encoded", so my guess is that you have a correct utf-8 String which hasnt the utf-8 flag on.

So add:

```
utf8::decode($subject_label);
```

add the top of the code, and leave the rest as is.

HTH
Georg

Comment: If that's the problem, a better explanation is: The OP didn't decode their inputs before encoding their outputs.

Comment: If i get the Encode-Package code correctly, Encode::_utf8_on just sets the utf_8 flag in place, decode_utf8 copies the string. So etiher you have to use, `Encode::_utf8_on($subject_label);` or `$subject_label=Encode::decode_utf8($subject_label);`

Comment: Indeed, `$subject_label=Encode::decode_utf8($subject_label);` would have been the proper usage. Use built-in `utf8::encode` if you want to do it in-place. Fixed. (NEVER EVER USE `_utf8_on`.)

Comment: utf8::encode and Encode::_utf8_on are two completely different things. One just turns on a flag, if a variable is wrongly MARKED as latin1. the other function does  re-encode something. See http://pastebin.com/76nK6uaU for a short example.

Comment: Argh, the in-place equivalent of `decode_utf8` is obviously `utf8::decode` not `utf8::encode`. Typo!! Many apologies!! (`utf8::decode($s)` is equivalent to `is_utf8($s) ? $s = decode_utf8($s) : _utf8_on($s)`)